# deploy a windows form application which links to two excel files created on visual studio 2010 on another system

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, deployment, exe

I have created a windows form application in visual studio 2010 which has 4 forms in it. 3 of these files are connected to 2 different excel files. Now, I want this application to run on another system which has the same excel files. I have just made the application but I am clueless on what to do in order to run it as an application on the other system.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are relying on "Interop" to communicate with Excel. In that case, you have to make sure that Microsoft Office is installed on the target computer. In order to avoid problems, confirm that the version is equal to the one you used to create the application.

If the target version of Office is 2007 or older, the Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies have to be installed on the given computer ([link to the 2007 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346)).